# SVN Merging a branch to another branch and the trunk

Tags: svn, merge, version-control, branch

Some background: 
I have a project trunk and two branches.  Branch A has changes to it and is waiting for others to review it before I can merge it back to the trunk. In the meantime I'm working on refactoring and cleaning up all of the code in general with Branch B.  I want the changes from Branch A on Branch B so I don't refactor anything that was changed in the Branch A and have weird conflicts.  I plan on merging Branch A back to the trunk in the meantime.

My Question:
If I merge Branch A to Branch B, then I merge Branch A to the trunk, will it cause problems with Branch B when I merge from the trunk to Branch B?  It seems like it would because both the trunk and Branch B at that point will have code that is the same, but was pulled in from Branch A.  Is svn able to handle such a case without it causing conflicts since both Branch B and the trunk were modified independently of one another?

Answer (score 0):

With "cyclic merge" weird (and almost not predictable) results are still very expectable (at least for SVN 1.9.*)

Another additional weighty argument in favor of migration to the Mercurial (where Merge-Hell is just unknown reality)